# Be able to select the correct text file based on option selected

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android app and just need some help on selecting the correct text files and keeping a count of the number of clicks for buttons.

So basically I have two activity classes. The homepage of the app is stored in the `MainActivity` class and the other class is known as `Content`

In the `MainActivity` class there are three buttons:
Jokes,
Poems
and Funny Stories

Basically whichever option the user selects out of those three buttons, the content on the next page (`Content` class) will display the correct passage of text relating to the choice selected.

Currently my code works for jokes when the user selects jokes and the content it displays is randomly selected from the `jokes.txt` file.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    final Context context = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button jokesButton = findViewById(R.id.button_jokes);
        Button poemsButton = findViewById(R.id.button_poems);
        Button funnyStoriesButton = findViewById(R.id.button_funny_stories);

        jokesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openContentPage();
            }
        });


    }

    private void openContentPage(){
        Intent intentContentPage = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Content.class);
        startActivity(intentContentPage);
    }

}
```

Content

```
public class Content extends AppCompatActivity{

    Button backButton;
    Button selectAnotherButton;
    TextView contentText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_content);

         backButton = findViewById(R.id.button_back);
         selectAnotherButton = findViewById(R.id.button_select_another);
         contentText = findViewById(R.id.content_text);
         contentText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

         setContent();

        selectAnotherButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    setContent();
                }
        });

            backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick (View v){
                backToMainActivity();
            }
        });
    }


    private void backToMainActivity(){
        Intent intentMainActivity = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intentMainActivity);
    }

    private void setContent(){
        String text = "";
        String randomJoke = "";

        try {
            // file to inputstream
            InputStream input = getAssets().open("files/jokes.txt");
            int size = input.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            input.read(buffer);
            input.close();
            // byte buffer into a string
            text = new String(buffer);

            String[] jokes = text.split("###");
            Random rand = new Random();
            int  randomIndex = rand.nextInt(jokes.length);
            randomJoke = jokes[randomIndex];

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        contentText.setText(randomJoke);

    }

}
```

However this code needs to be manipulated so that it includes Poems and Funny Stories. Basically if the user selects Poems then it will grab the content from the `poems.txt` file, if they select `Funny Stories` then it will grab from the `funnystories.txt` file. Also if they select the `Select Another` button, it will randomly select a new entry from the correct text file. Like I said the code I have done works for jokes only, but I need to make it more dynamic so it would work for poems and funny stories too depending on which option the user selected from the homepage.

One final thing as well. I want a count of the number of times the user has clicked on either Jokes, Poems, Funny Stories from `MainActivity` and also add Select Another button to the count as well.

How can this be implemented?

UPDATE:

Trying to receive the intent I receive the following error from this code:

```
private void setContent(){
        String text = "";
        String randomText = "";
        String keyPageValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("keyPage");

        String fileName = "";

        if(keyPageValue.equals("0")){
            fileName.equals("files/jokes.txt");
        }
        else if (keyPageValue.equals("1")){
            fileName.equals("files/poems.txt");
        }
        else if (keyPageValue.equals("2")){
            fileName.equals("files/funnystories.txt");
        }

        try {
            InputStream input = getAssets().open(fileName);

            int size = input.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            input.read(buffer);
            input.close();
            // byte buffer into a string
            text = new String(buffer);

            String[] splitText = text.split("###");
            Random rand = new Random();
            int  randomIndex = rand.nextInt(splitText.length);
            randomText = splitText[randomIndex];

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        contentText.setText(randomText);

    }
```

Stack Trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.mima.chilltime, PID: 18747
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mima.chilltime/com.mima.chilltime.Content}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3150)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260)
...
```

Comment: So you want to pass data between your two activities? See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application). As for counting the number of times the user has clicked, you could use [SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23024962/5288316). Also instead of restarting MainActivity to go back, just call `finish()`.

Comment: I'll have a little read Nicolas, thank you

Comment: @Nicolas Question, I understand on how the intent works if I am passing one value out of one, but as I am passing one value out of a possible three, should I have three intents? I am thinking looking at the example I am suppose to get the string and then I perform an if statement based on the string I pull?

Comment: I think I just need a little help with implementation on this

Comment: You can pass a single string value, the filename, assuming it is available in MainActivity. However, a better practice would be storing them in a helper class, or using Raj's way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do that you can pass an int value which denotes the type of button clicked by the user:-

```
jokesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        openContentPage(0);
    }
});

 poemsButton .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         openContentPage(1);
     }
 });

 funnyStoriesButton .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         openContentPage(2);
     }
 });

private void openContentPage(int v) {
    if(v == 0) {
        Intent intentContentPage = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Content.class);
        intent.putExtra("keyPage",0);
        startActivity(intentContentPage);
    }
    else if(v == 1) {
        Intent intentContentPage = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Content.class);
        intent.putExtra("keyPage",1);
        startActivity(intentContentPage);
    }
    else {
        Intent intentContentPage = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Content.class);
        intent.putExtra("keyPage",2);
        startActivity(intentContentPage);
    }
}
```

And in the next activity you can receive intent. Fetch the value and check based on that open the content page.

Comment: I'll give it a go and get back to you. Will be about 10 mins

Comment: Hi Raj, I provided an update, basically I am getting an error when trying to retreive the intent so thought of showing you to have your input on what I'm doing incorrectly

Comment: Also I have been looking at Shared preferences and wanted to know the correct way of implementing that for click count and that has caused me an issue as well before attempting your answer on the intent

Comment: I am passing an int value. So, you have to do :- int keyPageValue = getIntent().getIntExtra("keyPage");. And compare it as.                                 if(keyPageValue == 0){
            fileName = "files/jokes.txt";
        }

Comment: it expects a deafult int value after "keyPage" within:  int keyPageValue = getIntent().getIntExtra("keyPage")

Comment: so i gave default value -1 and run it but filename remains blanks when going through the the try catch statement and this is for the input strear